# Multiple inputs for Google Cardboard on iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, virtual-reality

So far I am having a problem with having only a singular input mechanism (the magnetic trigger) for Google Cardboard games.  Are there any other options to augment this in order to have at least two or three input "buttons" or triggers for a Cardboard app or are we stuck with one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only ways to add extra inputs is to either:

1. Connect a Bluetooth controller or another similar device.
2. Make your own custom Google Cardboard viewer with more buttons.

Comment: #2 is an interesting thought.  How would you even go about doing that?  What options to add buttons are there?  Another thought is, is the magnetometer able to sense some level of orientation of the magnetic field or a direction of the flux of the field so as to make different distinct motions act as distinct buttons?

Comment: I don't know about your viewer, @ylluminate, but mine simply has a pad that taps the phones screen; same as your finger would. You'd just have to add more of those at different positions.

Comment: What viewer do you have specifically that facilitates this?

Comment: I'm using an Unoffical Cardboard 2.0 Plus [link](http://www.unofficialcardboard.com/products/2-0-plus?variant=7602772993)